# How to Implement Custom office 365 Signin with Azure AD using asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, active-directory, office365

We are doing [Office 365 with asp.net mvc](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) , in this example working fine for me but the problem is when i click sign-in or any calendar button its redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com url after enter credentials its automatically redirect to home page with success login. **Now we are creating our own Custom login page** ([Ref link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-with-office-365-in-C-Sharp/)), How to authenticate and behave like same as a Microsoft login with out redirect to microsoft login page?

Can you help me to next step.

Thanks,
Hemanth.